# How to explain the counter/map in this oneline code to count the frequency of a 2d array

Tags: python

```
count = defaultdict(int, sum(map(Counter, board), Counter()))
```

board is a 2d array:  `List[List[str]]`

I can understand that this one-line code is to count the frequency of the board,
and we can write this way:

```
count = defaultdict(int)
for i in range(len(board)):
    for j in range(len(board[0]):
       count[board[i][j]] += 1
```

Could you help explain the one-line logic? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `board` is defined as such:

```
board = [["hello", "hello"], ["world", "hello"]]
```

The call to `map` gives us:

```
>>> list(map(Counter, board))
[Counter({'hello': 2}), Counter({'world': 1, 'hello': 1})]
```

We can try to sum these counters, but we will get an error:

```
>>> sum(map(Counter, board))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Counter'
```

So we provide an initial value other than the default `0`.

```
>>> sum(map(Counter, board), Counter())
Counter({'hello': 3, 'world': 1})
```

And then convert that to a `defaultdict` presumably for the sake of code that follows this line.

Comment: honestly, the call to `defaultdict` doesn't really make much sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! Yes, I tried and the `defaultdict` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

So, the explanation of the code is given in Chris's answer, but I think it should be noted that `sum(map(Counter, board), Counter())` is kinda inefficient, since it needs to re-create a new `Counter` object for each item in `board`, and then a new one for each internal iteration of the `sum`. In the worst case, where every item is unique (everything has a count of 1) this degenerates into quadratic time behavior. Observe:

```
In [5]: rs = [range(i, i+1000) for i in range(1, 10_000, 1000)]

In [6]: rs
Out[6]:
[range(1, 1001),
 range(1001, 2001),
 range(2001, 3001),
 range(3001, 4001),
 range(4001, 5001),
 range(5001, 6001),
 range(6001, 7001),
 range(7001, 8001),
 range(8001, 9001),
 range(9001, 10001)]

In [7]: %timeit sum(map(Counter, rs), Counter())
15.2 ms ± 155 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: counts = Counter()
   ...: for r in rs:
   ...:     counts.update(r)
   ...:
500 µs ± 5.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

So, right off the bat, we are orders of magnitude slower using the `map` vs the naive loop. 30 times slower. But look how it scales when we *double* the size:

```
In [15]: %timeit sum(map(Counter, rs), Counter())
60.9 ms ± 1.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [16]: %%timeit
    ...: counts = Counter()
    ...: for r in rs:
    ...:     counts.update(r)
    ...:
1.01 ms ± 8.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Here we see the quadratic behavior - the `map` version *quadrupled* in time, whereas the naive for-loop only doubled (linear scaling).

Let's double it yet again:

```
In [19]: rs = [range(i, i+1000) for i in range(1, 40_000, 1000)]

In [20]: %timeit sum(map(Counter, rs), Counter())
244 ms ± 8.96 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [21]: %%timeit
    ...: counts = Counter()
    ...: for r in rs:
    ...:     counts.update(r)
    ...:
2.13 ms ± 34.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The quadratic vs linear behavior still holds, and now the difference in time is 2 orders of magnitude, 100 times slower for the map version.